# testing local storage in angular and jasmine

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I have the following LocalStorage factory

```
    (function () {

  angular.module('xxxx.factories', [])

  .factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
      set: function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = value;
      },
      get: function(key, defaultValue) {
        return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
      },
      setObject: function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
      },
      getObject: function(key) {
        return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
      }
    }
  }]);

})();
```

I have my jasmine test

```
    describe('Application Start Ctrl', function () {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('xxxx.controllers'));

    var $controller, $window;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$controller_, _$window_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $window = _$window_;
    }));


    describe('Register', function () {
        it('Application Started', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var $inject = angular.injector(['xxxx.services', 'xxxx.factories']);
            var setupService = $inject.get('$SetupService');
            var localstorage = $inject.get('$localstorage');
            var controller = $controller('ApplicationStartCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $SetupService: setupService, $localstorage: localstorage });
            $scope.getstarted();
            expect($scope.started).toBe(true);
        });
    });


});
```

I get the following error:

*Unknown provider: $windowProvider <- $window <- $localstorage*

I can see that my factory has dependancy for $window. I just wrap my head around how to inject this into my test.